# Regex to match only certain characters or strings and only one instance of each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web

I feel like I know just enough about Regexes to get stuck. That said, I have an input field which will allow users to enter their currency symbol. I'm only wanting to allow said currency symbol and disallow anything else from being entered into that field. Some countries don't actually have a single symbol, but are just two or three characters, e.g., "Kr" for Krona. So the field has a max length of 3. Given it needs a max length of three to accommodate some currencies, I also don't want to allow three dollar signs to be entered, e.g., "$$$". I would only want to allow one single dollar, pound, euro, etc. sign.

Here's my basic code for allowing only these symbos in the input:

```
$('#id_currency_symbol').on('input',function (){
    var value = $(this).val().toString();
    newvalue = value.replace(/[^$£€¥₣₩￦￥₽₺₹Rkr]+/g,'');
    $(this).val(newvalue);
});
```

This works for only allowing these symbols/letters, but like I said above, I don't want to allow users to enter more than a single instance of some symbols, i.e. dollar sign ($). In addition, I want to match exact strings for cases where the "symbol" is actually just two or three characters. In the case of Krona, the "symbol" is Kr. Given the above, users could in theory enter "rK" and it would be perfectly valid according to the regex, but I would ONLY want to allow the exact match of "Kr." Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: It would make far more sense to let people choose their currency from a dropdown list. Validating all possible values in a freetext field will be next to impossible.

Comment: Perhaps let the user enter whatever they wish, and then in the `blur` event look at the value and, if the user entered the same character three times, reduce that to one single character? This may suffer in the event that a legitimate currency symbol (and their are many symbols, I suspect) repeats the same character three times.

Comment: Try this `/(?:$|Kr)/`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanYeah I had considered that as an option too but figured the dropdown could potentially get quite long which isn't great for usability. That said, I think I'm leaning toward only including the most popular currencies anyway which would likely be 10-15 or so (I really don't need every single currency out there for my purposes) which a drop-down wouldn't be a terrible idea if it's that limited of a number.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the first occurrence of a currency symbol or acronym using a regex and then replace the whole input with the matched string. Single character currencies can be listed in `[...]` and any longer string may be added by alternation:

```js
var checkInput = function(input) {
  var regex = /[$£€¥₣₩￦￥₽₺₹]|kr/i;
  input = regex.exec(input);
  return input == null ? "" : input[0];
}

console.log(checkInput("lkjahfkdshfjsdf Kr asdasda"));
console.log(checkInput("kr"));
console.log(checkInput("rk"));
console.log(checkInput("$$$"));
console.log(checkInput("₣₩￦"));
console.log(checkInput("ABC"));
```

---

For completeness:

1. The *"Regex to match only certain characters or strings and only one instance of each"*:

   ```
   ^(?:[$£€¥₣₩￦￥₽₺₹]|kr)$
   ```

   Demo: https://regex101.com/r/w9p9d9/1
2. Regex to strip off anything but *"certain characters or strings"* and these characters too if they appear more than once (for use within `newvalue = value.replace(...,'');`):

   ```
   ^(?=.*?([$£€¥₣₩￦￥₽₺₹]|kr)|).*
   ```

   Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qocsv5/1

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. These seem to do what I need, but I'm having trouble getting them to work in the code I presented above. It seems when I use the code you gave (either option) that it will allow any other characters to be entered into the input except those found in the regex. What can I change to only allow those characters found in the regex? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to forget regex, and go for O(1) algos,

```
var allowedCurrencyCodes = {
      "$":true,
      "¢":true,
      "£":true,
      "INR":true,
      "Kr":true,
      .....,
      .....,
      .....
}
    $(this).val(allowedCurrencyCodes[$(this).val()]?$(this).val():"");
```

you need to perform the check at blur event or when user has entered at least 3 chars, else it becomes buggy as it will keep on wiping the data right after first char.

if you want to keep check real time i.e. responsive when user is typing in, then you need to change the structure of `allowedCurrencyCodes` and convert it to nested object for multi-char currency codes, e.g $,£ would be exactly same but INR or Kr will be defined like

```
"I":{
    "N":{
        "R":true
    }
},
"K":{
    "r":true
}
```

and minor change in fetch logic will be applied, where you will capture input and split it in array and then dip in `allowedCurrencyCodes` based on input chars, like

`allowedCurrencyCodes[inputChar[0]][inputChar[1]]`

or

`allowedCurrencyCodes[inputChar[0]][inputChar[1]][inputChar[2]]`